# show a webpage as showdialog

Tags: php, html, web

I am a C# Desktop Application developer and I am making a web application in PHP

In C# I use ShowDialog to display a form, I want to know how can I do same in PHP.

any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. You can create a DIV element and operate this with JavaScript, so this could be for example like modal form.

You can also open a small window by JavaScript and use this as a form -- this however is in fact another browser window.

Your question has in fact nothing common with PHP.

**EDIT**

If you choose to use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), a JavaScript library, there is nice [UI framwework](http://jqueryui.com/). You might be interested in [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).